# are 17W i3-i5 processors silent?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I need a quiet but "fast" laptop. My previous *Pentium P6200* machine was very quiet. I'm going to return a laptop with *i5 3230M* because it is too noisy. Now I'm thinking about something less powerfull. I have discovered low-power consuming **i3** and **i5** processors that consume just **17W** (e.g. **i3 3217U**, **i5 3337U**). But their performance according to the benchmarks is quiet good. Wiil a laptop with one of these processors be quieter? Or power consumption is not the only factor...

Comment: Try reading a review of a laptop with one of these processors. They often include sound levels.

Comment: They still have a fan.  You won't get a fanless Ivybridge or Haswell laptop.

Comment: This is going to be a factor of how fast (rpm) and loud the fans and drives spin rather than how much power is being used.  Lower power consumption could mean less heat and therefore less fan speed needed to cool, and maybe less noise, but the processors themselves aren't your noise generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, a low-power CPU is one that does not get too hot and, therefore, does not require a fast spinning fan. So yes, it should be quieter.

In general though it is not only the CPU's fan that makes noise, there are various other components that also add to it. While in laptops the most obvious is the CPU's fan, on desktops the Power Supply Unit also adds a lot of noise. In a laptop, apart from the CPU's fan you should also consider the graphics card's fan: a laptop with integrated, low-end graphics will make less noise than one with a discrete, high-end GPU since the latter will have its own fan.

Finally, you should also consider the hard drives since they can also be quite noisy. For a truly silent laptop, get one with a low power CPU, on board graphics and SSD hard drives. Some of the newer Macs for example have such large heat sinks and dissipate heat so efficiently that the fan is turned on very rarely.

These sites are very useful when hunting for silence:

- http://www.silentpcreview.com/
- http://www.quietpc.com/

Comment: One thing to consider as well is quality of build and how the fans are serviced.  For example, the Surface Pro and many HPs use PWMs without filters, so you *can* get a high pitched squeal.  Hard to tell these things without reviews, of course.  Great answer.